# Access multiple outputs from a script by symbolic names (keys)

Tags: powershell, hashtable, key-value, pscustomobject

I'm a beginner in powershell scripting, I want to be able to distinguish between the outputs of a script. Lets take as an example this script test.ps1:

```
param([System.String] $w)
$x=$w+" is correct"
$y=$w+ " is false"
$x
$y
```

to execute it and retrieve the values $x & $y, I'm doing this:

```
$a=.\test1.ps1 -w test
$a[0] #this is x
$a[1] # this is y
```

is there a way we can use something similar to $a.x to retrieve the $x value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want, you will need an object that contains a key/value pair or named properties. For example, you can create an object called `a` with properties `x` and `y`:

```
$x = "one"
$y = "two"
$a = [pscustomobject]@{"x"=$x;"y"=$y}
```

**Testing the Above Case:**

```
$a

x   y
-   -
one two

$a.x
one
$a.y
two
```

I like the link [PSCustomObjects](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/) for an explanation of creating and using custom objects.

**Testing with a Function:**

```
function test {

param([string] $w)

$x = $w + "x"
$y = $w + "y"

[pscustomobject]@{"x"=$x; "y"=$y}
}

$a = test "my property "
$a

x             y
-             -
my property x my property y


$a.x
my property x
$a.y
my property y
```

Answer (score 0):

[AdminOfThings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54985303/45375) shows one approach to providing key-based access to values, a **`[pscustomobject]`**.

In general terms, you're looking for a ***dictionary* or *hash table*** (hashtable): a collection of key-value pairs that allow efficient lookup of a value by its associated key.

In fact, the `[pscustomobject]` technique in the linked answer is syntactically based on PowerShell's *hashtable literal* syntax, `@{ <key> = <value>; ... }`<sup>[1]</sup>.

Example using a script block (`{ ... }`) instead of a script/function for brevity:

```
$output = & { 
  # Output a hashtable
  @{ x = 'one'; y = 'two' } 
}

# Access the entries by key:

# Index syntax:
$output['x'] # -> 'one'
$output['y'] # -> 'two'

# Dot notation, as with objects, works too.
# While this is convenient, it is much slower with variable-based keys;
# e.g., $output.$keyName - this typically won't matter, but may in loops
# with a high number of iterations.
$output.x # -> 'one'
$output.y # -> 'two'
```

If the order in which entries are enumerated matters, use an ***ordered* hashtable** (PSv3+): `[ordered] @{ <key> = <value>; ... }`.
You only pay a negligible performance penalty for using an ordered hashtable, so I suggest using `[ordered]` as a matter of habit, as it makes for a nicer output and debugging experience to see the entries in the same order in which they were defined.

---

**Choosing between a `[pscustomobject]` and a hashtable:**

- If you conceive of the output as a single object with the values stored in properties, use `[pscustomobject]`, but note that constructing an object is slower than constructing a hashtable.
- If the output is just a collection of key-value pairs, use a(n ordered) hashtable.

**If performance matters** (in loops with many iterations):

- Use (ordered) *hashtables*.
- Use *index access* with non-literal keys (e.g., `$key = 'one'; $ht[$key]`), which is much faster than non-literal dot notation (e.g., `$key = 'one'; $ht.$key`)

---

<sup>[1] Note, however, that `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is *syntactic sugar* in that a custom object is *directly* constructed - no intermediate hashtable is created; additionally, the properties defined by the hashtable keys are defined in *definition order*, whereas a hashtable guarantees no particular ordering of its entries unless you use `[ordered] @{ ... }`.</sup>